# How to get XPath for data table with two td and it should be clickable at once?

Tags: java, html, css, xpath

```
<div class="dataTables_scrollBody" style="position: relative; overflow: auto; height: 370px; width: 100%; min-height: 0px;">
<table id="offer_create" class="display article-list ranklist_drag table table-bordered dataTable no-footer" aria-describedby="offer_create_info" role="grid" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%;" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd" role="row">

    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test2</td>
</tr>
```

How to get XPath and its in data table to be clickable at once?

Check for image data table looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement htmltable=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/table[1]/tbody"));
List<WebElement> rows=htmltable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

for(int rnum=0;rnum<rows.size();rnum++)
{
List<WebElement> columns=rows.get(rnum).findElements(By.tagName("th"));
System.out.println("Number of columns:"+columns.size());

for(int cnum=0;cnum<columns.size();cnum++)
{
System.out.println(columns.get(cnum).getText());
}
}

Note: <tr> represent your row name and <th> represent your column name here.
```